# Abouts setting up two levels renderer, the top level will not be displayed completely

Tags: vtk

I set two layers of render, the first layer shows the larger actor, the second layer shows the smaller actor, to achieve the effect of the small actor on top of the large actor, but after the camera is rotated, the large actor will not be displayed completely. It should be calculated according to the front and back truncation size of the camera. How to deal with this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8stZ.png)

i use code:

```
volumeRenderer_->SetLayer(0);
tagRenderer_->SetLayer(1);
GetRenderWindow()->SetNumberOfLayers(2);
GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(tagRenderer_);
GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(volumeRenderer_);
```